# Cocoa merge 2 Images and save them

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

im trying to merge 2 different images in Cocoa and like to save the resulting image in my application. What I've done so far is this:

```
-(void)mergeImage:(NSImage*)target withImage:(NSImage*)source {
    [target lockFocus];

    NSPoint aPoint;
    aPoint.x = 1;
    aPoint.y = 1;
    [source drawAtPoint:aPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [target unlockFocus];

    NSBitmapImageRep *bmpImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[target TIFFRepresentation]];

    [target addRepresentation:bmpImageRep];

    NSData *data = [bmpImageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType
                                             properties: nil];

    NSURL* aURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];

    NSString *tmpPathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tempImage.png", aURL]];
    [data writeToFile:tmpPathToFile atomically:YES];
}
```

I don't get any error, the urls to the bundle seem to be correct. And the "data" holds ~2,9MB 2985448

Comment: You are not (or should not be) allowed to to write to the application bundle.  They're sealed for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is your app sandboxed? If so make sure it does allow writing to the directory you're writing to.
2. Is there already a file with the same name? `atomically` won't overwrite it.
3. Is the file path correct?

---

Just like [CodaFi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945847/codafi) mentioned it, you are not allowed to write to the application bundle.
You can, however, write to the application support folder. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Oh, ok. That means also temporary data has to go into the application support folder?

Comment: @mightym It depends on what you call temporary. If it's really temporary, which can be deleted after the computer shuts down, there is a special temporary directory you can use. Using `NSTemporaryDirectory();`. Or if it's something your app will use later, you'll want to save it in the application support folder.

Comment: Ah perfect! i had no idea that sth. like NSTemporaryDirectory exists. Thank you very much for!